# Получить список параметров, python3.x argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Запускаю фаил в командной строке с такими аргументами:

```
python test.py -f a.jpg b.jpg -t png
```

как получить список файлов `a.jpg b.jpg` ? использую библиотеку argparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы получить аргументы как список нужно использовать nargs='+'. В документации описано как можно интерпретировать количество параметров используя nargs https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='description')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', nargs='+')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

При вызове скрипта с параметрами получим следующий вывод

```
python test.py -l q a 1
Namespace(list=['q', 'a', '1'])
```